# how can I connect the most colored chords in a circle using a dynamic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

the goal is to create a circle with the most colored (by colored I mean they must connect 2 points of the same color) chords given the order of points on the circle and 5 different colors are possible.there is also one single black bead in the n+1 position

I thought about maybe converting all possible chords to segments and find the largest amount of non intersecting segments. I had a really hard time understanding how you could do that using a dynamic algorithm

Comment: As far as I can see, you have a circle, points (of at most `5` different colors) on it. You can connect 2 points of the *same* color with a chord. Your task is to draw as many chords as you can. There's an extra condition: chords must not intersect (but can share a point on the circle). Is it your task?

Comment: yes that is the task

Comment: When a chord is added, the problem is reduced to two disjoint subproblems. Each subproblem needs to be solved only once. That's the basis for all dynamic programming algorithms.

Comment: my problem is that I can't really understand which subproblems I can divide this to while still adhering to the conditions of no intersection and only same color beads being connected

Comment: Here is a huge hint. Points are indexed `0, 1, 2, ..., n-1` clockwise around the circle. Then the best chord-combination using points a to b either uses point b or doesn't use point b. If it doesn't use point b, then it's same as best chord-combination using a to b-1. If it uses point b, then point b is used with point c chosen among all points in (a, a + 1, ..., b-1) which have same colour as b. Then, chord [c,b] divides the circle into two subproblems, the subproblem of best chord-combnation using points (a, ..., c-1) and the subproblem of best chord-combination using points (c+1, b-1).

Comment: Please explain the significance of "one single black bead in the n+1 position".  Can or must black be one of the colors? Can there be a chord from, say, position n-2 to position 2, when those two points are the same color?